# How do I force the Box Select tool to show up in a plotly graph?

Tags: javascript, plotly

I'm following this example for selecting a region of interest in plotly:

http://codepen.io/etpinard/pen/zBWRZb

```
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="graph"></div>
</body>

<script>
var gd = document.getElementById('graph');
var d3 = Plotly.d3;
var formatter = d3.format('.2f');

Plotly.plot(gd, [{
  mode: 'lines',
  x: Array.apply(null, Array(100)).map(() => Math.random()),
  y: Array.apply(null, Array(100)).map(() => Math.random()),
}], {
  dragmode: 'select'
});

gd.on('plotly_selected', (eventData) => {
  var xRange = eventData.range.x;
  var yRange = eventData.range.y;

  Plotly.relayout('graph', 'title',
`x range: [${xRange.map(formatter).join(', ')}]<br>
 y range: [${yRange.map(formatter).join(', ')}]`
  );
});
</script>
```

However, when I change the mode value to be "lines" instead of "markers", the box select button is not present in the plot (should normally be next to the pan button).  I'm still able to do a box select as soon as the page renders, but if I were to select the zoom tool there is no way to go back to box select.

Comment: Any feedback for me?

Comment: Hi Jon, did you look at my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that one can explicitly specify which buttons should be present:

```
Plotly.plot(gd,
            [
                {
                    type: "scatter",
                    x: time,
                    y: current,
                }
            ],
            {},
            {modeBarButtons:
             [
                 ['zoom2d'],
                 ['zoomIn2d'],
                 ['zoomOut2d'],
                 ['autoScale2d'],
                 ['select2d'],
                 ['toImage']
             ]
            }
           );
```

This seems to force these buttons to appear regardless of plot type.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is by design, as you can only really select markers, so if there are none, there is nothing to select. Nothing is stopping you from using both at the same time however, modifying your code to look something like this:

```
xvals = Array.apply(null, Array(100)).map(() => Math.random());
yvals = Array.apply(null, Array(100)).map(() => Math.random());   
Plotly.plot(gd, [{
  mode: 'lines',
  x: xvals,
  y: yvals,
},{
  mode: 'markers',
  x: xvals,
  y: yvals,
}], {
  dragmode: 'select'
});
```

If you need the markers to be invisible, you can adjust their size to be smaller than the line width and make the `markers` and the `lines` to have the same color.